# Any Built-in Function for Beta, Co-variance and Variance in SQL Server2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is the Any Built-in Function for Beta, Co-variance and Variance in SQL Server2008.

These are available in MS Excel, Beta=BETADIST(), Co-variance=COVAR() and Variance=VAR()

I can do it by calculating step by step. But if there is any built-in function then it will save my time.

Thanks in Advance!!!

> N.B. Oh I got VAR() in SQL Server, Now I need Beta and Co-variance

Comment: Can you add table structure for BETADIST please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sample data from the [Excel COVAR docs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/covar-HP005209036.aspx)

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (x decimal(19,6), y  decimal(19,6));
INSERT @MyTable (x, y) VALUES (3, 9), (2, 7), (4, 12), (5, 15), (6, 17);
```

Covariance is this

```
SELECT
    SUM(x * y) / COUNT(*) - AVG(x) * AVG(y)
FROM
    @MyTable
```

..which is equivalent to the more complex and slower

```
SELECT  SUM((x - AvgX) * (y - AvgY)) / COUNT(*)
FROM 
    (
     SELECT
         x, y,
         AVG(x) OVER () AS AvgX,
         AVG(y) OVER () AS AvgY
     FROM
         @MyTable
    ) T;
```

[BETADIST](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/betadist-HP005209000.aspx) is trickier: what table structure are you using for what parameters

Comment: Thanks, but which one is faster, first one or second?